# large gap between floor tile and wall tile using Schluter DILEX EKE profile

Tags: shower, tiling

I have installed Schluter DILEX EKE profiles around the perimeter of the Schluter shower tray and tiled the floor. The DILEX EKE serve the purpose of a movement joint at the junction of the shower wall and floor. In preparation for tiling the wall, I dry-fit a 24 x 48 tile on top of the DILEX EKE, and I note a ~1cm height gap between the tiled floor and the bottom of the wall tile; only about half the gap is filled by the EKE. Also, the 24 x 48 tile is convex at floor level, so the tile is sticking out from the wall about 0.5cm deep near the middle.

I am now concerned that the gap is quite large and the final result will be not be esthetically appealing. How would you go about compensating or correcting for the height and depth gaps to yield an esthetically good result?

[image: View of the ~1cm gap between the tiled floor and the wall tile.]

Answer (score 1):

I actually called Schluter tech support. They had no ideal solution here. If the All-Set would have been still fresh (< 1 day), he would have recommended to pull it out, but my installation was done about 3 weeks ago, so removing it now would damage the membrane.

The best reco they gave me was to cut out the EKE, trying not to damage the KERDI membrane. In case the membrane is damaged, use KERDI-FIX to fix it. Then, install tiles and grout over.

They told me that in retrospect the BWA profile would have been better for my application, which contradicts official Schluter information about DILEX EKE (https://www.schluter.ca/schluter-ca/en_CA/Profiles/Cove-shaped-Profiles/Schluter%C2%AE-DILEX-EKE/p/DILEX_EKE), where it says the EKE is an "ideal profile for showers". I was a bit shocked to be told that the EKE should not have been used.

As a conclusion, these EKE profiles ended up being quite a waste of my time and money.